# From Exchange email body information to SharePoint columns

Tags: list, workflow, incoming-email

I have come into a position where there is an application sending an email message with information in the body regarding an order.  It is currently a manual process to open the email message (from Exchange 365), open the SharePoint site, and manually create a List Item for the order.  I am looking to automate this process.

There could be multiple items being ordered in the email body, and number and item need to go to one column (Description).  Also in the body is Ship To, part of which goes to "Title", and part is being made into a google maps link for directions to the location, and goes to a "Google Maps" column; and a Comments section (which there may be none, or a few lines of them), which goes to "Comments".

The email body contains an HTML table when it arrives.

I initially used Flow to create a SP List Item in a separate list (Incoming), with Subject in one column, and the Body in a separate column.  I was then working to create a Visual Basic workflow to parse the body, gather the information, and create the new List Item.  However, I am not sure how to read and then assign values to columns in a VB SharePoint workflow.

Is this even the best way?  Should the email message be broken apart prior to being imported into SharePoint?  Is there a better tool to break it apart while importing to SharePoint?  Has all of this been addressed in a separate article that I have missed?

Is this possible with a SharePoint Online solution, or is custom code only available to on-site solutions?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint do you have? I guess it's on premise SP since you mentioned Visual Basic workflow?

Comment: SharePoint 365.  I can only do VB if it is on prem?